# How to save selected div display after refresh page with localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have issued, how to make a remember div show and hide on refresh page using localstorage?

After i click on up right side RUB or UAH it executing script to show and hide currency on details, but when reload the page it's again dissapear.

this is code of this script:

```
         function loadAfterTime() {

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#uahid").click(function(){
                $("#total > div:nth-child(1), #c_cost > b:nth-child(2), #c_cost > b:nth-child(1), #local_delivery_prices > div:nth-child(1)").show();
                $("#total > div:nth-child(3), #c_cost > b:nth-child(8), #c_cost > b:nth-child(7), #local_delivery_prices > div:nth-child(3), #c_cost > b:nth-child(5)").hide();
            });
         });


         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#rubid").click(function(){
                $("#total > div:nth-child(3), #c_cost > b:nth-child(8), #c_cost > b:nth-child(7), #local_delivery_prices > div:nth-child(3), #c_cost > b:nth-child(5)").show();
                $("#total > div:nth-child(1), #c_cost > b:nth-child(2), #c_cost > b:nth-child(1), #local_delivery_prices > div:nth-child(1)").hide();
            });
         });

         }
```

Comment: So, what did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried to use http://meest-shop.com/js/cookiems.js with cookie, but doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried, we'll try and debug it, but we won't create the whole thing for you, that's not how SO works.

Comment: you could save a boolean on the localstorage than check if it is true of false and show based on that

Comment: http://meest-shop.com/js/cookiems.js this is the code that i tried...

Answer (score 2):

You can give an unique ID to these div and store these IDs with each state hidden or shown in localStorage when you change it. Maybe after each hide/show call you could do `localStorage.setItem('item' + ID, state)`. With `state` equal to hidden or shown then after refresh you read it to know what it’s the previous state and apply it.